# How Windows Mutex and waitforsingleobject works internally

Tags: c++, synchronization, window, mutex

How Windows Mutex works internally ? I know theories and example and usage over it.
Is it s kernel object ? 
what means that WaitForSinleObject() blocks a thread when mutex state is nonsignaled ? 
how the blocked thread list gets maintained ?

I wish to know internals.

Comment: You are better off starting with Linux or any other OS with open source. Check [eventfd](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/fs/eventfd.c) sources, specifically function `eventfd_read`. It shows how kernel blocks calling thread.

Comment: Sure , so Mutex is kernel object which we request when we do CreateMutex ?

Comment: Yes. Linux sources can serve as an example of how waiting queue for threads is implement. Windows will implement it in a similar way.